# Alternative Construction of Sheaf from Sheaf on a Base

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

In Vakil's Notes and Mumford's 'Algebraic Geometry II', one can find the usual recovery of a sheaf from the data on the base using stalks. I was wondering if this construction would work too.

Suppose $\mathscr F$ is a sheaf on bases of a topological space $X$. For an open set $U\subset X$ where $U$ is open, define

$\bar{\mathscr F}(U)=\varprojlim_{B\subset U}\mathscr F(B)$, where the $B$s are basic open sets.

This seems to satisfy all the sheaf conditions since limits commute with products and kernels and hence the equalizer diagram for sheaves is satisfied. But I must have overlooked something since I haven't seen this anywhere else. Could you tell me if I'm right?

Comment: What kind of limit is that?

Comment: An inverse limit.

Comment: An inverse limit? Over what ordered set/category?

Comment: The category of the Basic open sets and the restriction maps.

Comment: I got this idea from the fact that for any sheaf $\mathscr F$, $\mathscr F(U)=lim_{U_{i}\subset U} \mathscr F(U_{i})$ for any open covering $\{U_{i}\}$ of $U$

Comment: So the basic open sets contained in $U$? You may be on to something there, but I suspect what you would get is a presheaf, which you would then have to sheafify.

Comment: The sheaf obtained from a sheaf on the base is unique and a morphism of sheaves (so in particular an isomorphism of sheaves) is determined by a morphism (resp. isomorphism) on the base. Can you write down a map on the between your object and Vakil's on the level of basic opens? Alternatively, you can look up what a cofinal system is and how inverse limits over cofinal systems work.

Comment: Yes, I can in fact show a map between any open sets as follows: For any $x\in U$, $\bar{\mathscr F}(U)\to \mathscr F(B)\to \mathscr F_{x} $, where $B$ is a basic open set contained in $U$ containing $x$ and the maps are the usual ones associated to the limits. This is easily shown to be well defined. That this is an isomorphism seems harder to prove.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you should compute what $\overline{\mathscr{F}}(B)$ is for basic opens $B$.

Comment: $\bar{\mathscr F}(B) =\mathscr F(B)$ for basic open sets $B$. This is easily verified from the definition of a limit.

Comment: Thus if you have been able to show that $\overline{\mathscr{F}}$ is a sheaf, you're done! They're isomorphic on the level of basic opens so they're isomorphic as sheaves.

Comment: For reference, this is Proposition I-12 in Eisenbud-Harris, "Geometry of Schemes".

Comment: I believe this is Grothedieck's original construction in EGA I. I'll try to find a precise reference later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a construction works: here's a [reference](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Eedix/alggeom2005/notes-7-3.pdf) (title: "Construction of a sheaf from the data on a basis of open sets"). [Here](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/eisenbudharris.pdf) (pp. 26) is the one pointed out by @DKS in the comments.

---

**Edit** (two years later!): A conceptual way to look at this construction is that the formula
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\mathscr{F}(U)\cong\underset{\overset{\longleftarrow}{B\subset U}}{\lim}(\mathscr{F}(B))\end{equation}
is precisely the usual formula computing right Kan extensions. Let $\mathsf{Open}(X)$ be the category whose

- Objects are the open subsets of $X$;
- Morphisms are inclusions.

Given a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $X$, write $\mathsf{Open}(\mathcal{B})$ for the full subcategory of $\mathsf{Open}(X)$ spanned by the opens of $X$ in $\mathcal{B}$. Then we have a canonical inclusion
$$
    i\colon\mathsf{Open}(\mathcal{B})\hookrightarrow\mathsf{Open}(X),
$$
and the *presheaf* associated to a presheaf $\mathscr{F}\colon\mathsf{Open}(\mathcal{B})^\mathsf{op}\to\mathcal{A}$ on the basis $\mathcal{B}$ taking values on a category $\mathcal{A}$ is precisely the right Kan extension of $\mathscr{F}$ along $i$:

[image]

You can go from this to Equation $(1)$ by computing $\mathsf{Ran}_i(\mathscr{F})$ as the limit [in Eq. 6.2.3 of Riehl's book](http://www.math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf):

[image],

which in our context takes the form
$$
    \mathscr{F}(U)\cong\lim\left((\underline{U}\downarrow i)^\mathsf{op}\twoheadrightarrow\mathsf{Open}(\mathcal{B})^\mathsf{op}\overset{\mathscr{F}}{\longrightarrow}\mathcal{A}\right).
$$
But $(\underline{U}\downarrow i)^\mathsf{op}$ is precisely the category whose objects are inclusions of the form $B\hookrightarrow U$ for $B\in\mathcal{B}$, so projecting from this to $\mathsf{Open}(\mathcal{B})^\mathsf{op}$ and then applying $\mathscr{F}$ recovers Eq. $(1)$.

For *sheaves*, you first take the right Kan extension of $\mathscr{F}$ on $\mathcal{B}$ as above and then sheafify. If $\mathscr{F}$ is already a sheaf on $\mathcal{B}$, then so is the resulting sheaf on $X$ ([Görtz–Wedhorn, Prop. 2.20](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783834897220#otherversion=9783834806765)).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your construction works and indeed this is how Grothendieck defines the sheaf induced by a sheaf on a base in [EGA I](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/grothendieckcircle/EGA/EGAI.pdf).

Let $\mathcal{K}$ be a category. In paragraph (3.2.1) (p. 26), given a sheaf $\mathscr F$ on a base $\mathscr B$ of open sets, he defines a sheaf $\mathscr F'$ by
$$
\mathscr{F}'(U) = \varprojlim_V \mathscr{F}(V)
$$
where $V$ ranges over the ordered set of sets $V \in \mathscr{B}$ with $V \subseteq U$.

He remarks in paragraph (3.2.6):

> Assume still that $\mathcal{K}$ admits projective limits. Then the
>   category of sheaves on $X$ with values in $\mathcal{K}$ also admits
>   projective limits;...the verification of axiom (F) [the sheaf axiom]
>   results from the transitivity of projective limits...